# Improving the efficiency of bootstrapping algorithm for large matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, tensorflow

I am working on improving the efficiency of a bootstrapping algorithm written in python. The computational speed is ok when the size of the the matrix is relatively small, but it slows down significantly when n and k are large.

Because the algorithm is essentially array manipulation, is there anyway to improve the efficiency of it by either optimizing the algorithm itself or by rewriting it in order to use packages such as pycuda/tensorflow etc. as GPU resources are accessible?

```
import numpy as np
n = 5000
k = 3000
ary = np.random.choice([0,1],size=(n,k))
lst = []
cols = list(range(ary.shape[1]))
while len(lst) < ary.shape[1]:
    print(len(lst), ary.shape[1])
    a = [lst+[x] for x in cols]
    b = [ary[:,x] for x in a]
    c = np.asarray(b)
    d = c.sum(axis=2)
    d = np.repeat(d[..., None], c.shape[-1], 2)
    d1 = np.divide(c, d)
    d2 = np.nanmean(d1, axis=1)
    d2 = np.nan_to_num(d2)
    d3 = d2[:, -1]
    d4 = d3 / np.sum(d3)
    lst.extend([np.random.choice(cols, p=d4)])
    print(d4.shape)
    print(lst)
```

Comment: Whyare you using `nan_to_num`, then using `nansum` on the result? You already replaced all the nans!